# Lubridate divide interval spanning leap day by year error

Tags: r, lubridate

Can someone shed some light on why the following produces an error:

```
library(lubridate)

start_leap  = ymd('1992-02-29')
end_leap    = ymd('1992-03-01')
interv_leap = start_leap %--% end_leap

interv_leap %/% years(1)
#> Error in while (any(start + est * per < end)) est[start + est * per <  : 
#>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

but this doesn't:

```
start  = ymd('1993-02-28')
end    = ymd('1993-03-01')
interv = start %--% end

interv %/% years(1)
#> 0
```

I thought this might have to do with dividing by periods, but all of the following are fine:

```
interv %/% days(1)
interv %/% months(1)    
interv %/% ddays(1)
interv %/% dyears(1)

interv_leap %/% days(1)
interv_leap %/% months(1)    
interv_leap %/% ddays(1)
interv_leap %/% dyears(1)
```

References to documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Strangely, the first works and the second fails for me.

Comment: ack sorry @Pascal, I copy-pasted in the wrong order. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Looks similar to [this report](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/issues/235)

Comment: Dang I was hoping it wouldn't be a bug. Thanks for finding the report.